# How can I avoid calling a stored procedure from a UDF in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Before I start, I know you can't call a stored procedure from a UDF and I know that there are various "reasons" for this (none that make much sense to me though, tbh it just sounds like laziness on Microsoft's part).

I am more interested in how I can design a system to get round this flaw in SQL Server.

This is a quick overview of the system I currently have:

- I have a dynamic report generator where users specify data items, operators (=, <, !=, etc.) and filter values.  These are used to build up "rules" with one or more filters, e.g. I might have a rule that has two filters "Category < 12" and "Location != 'York'";
- there are thousands and thousands of these "rules", some of them have many, many filters;
- the output from each of these rules is a statuory report that always has exactly the same "shape", i.e. the same columns/ data types.  Basically these reports produce lists of tonnages and materials;
- I have a scalar-valued function that generates Dynamic SQL for a specified rule, returning this as a VARCHAR(MAX);
- I have a stored procedure that is called to run a specific rule, it calls the UDF to generate the Dynamic SQL, runs this and returns the results (this used to just return the results but now I store the output in process-keyed tables to make the data easier to share and so I return a handle to this data instead);
- I have a stored procedure that is called to run all the rules for a particular company, so it makes a list of the rules to run, runs them sequentially and then merges the results together as output.

So this all works perfectly.

Now I want one final thing, a report that runs the company summary and then applies costs to the tonnages/ materials to result in a cost report.  This seemed such a simple requirement when I started on this last week :'(

My report has to be a table-valued function for it to work with the report broker system I have already written.  If I write it as a stored procedure then it will not be run through my report broker which means that it will not be controlled, i.e. I won't know who ran the report and when.

But I can't call a stored procedure from within a table-valued function and the two obvious ways to handle this are as follows:

1. Get the SQL to create the output, run it and suck up the results.

   ```
   --Method #1
   WHILE @RuleIndex <= @MaxRuleIndex
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @DSFId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
   SELECT @DSFId = [GUID] FROM NewGUID; --this has to be deterministic, it isn't but the compiler thinks it is and that's good enough :D
   DECLARE @RuleId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
   SELECT @RuleId = DSFRuleId FROM @DSFRules WHERE DSFRuleIndex = @RuleIndex;
   DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

   --Get the SQL
   SELECT @SQL = DSF.DSFEngine(@ServiceId, @MemberId, @LocationId, @DSFYear, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @DSFId, @RuleId);

   --Run it
   EXECUTE(@SQL);

   --Copy the data out of the results table into our local copy
   INSERT INTO 
       @DSFResults 
   SELECT 
       TableId, TableCode, TableName, RowId, RowName, LocationCode, LocationName, ProductCode, ProductName, PackagingGroupCode, PackagingGroupName, LevelName, WeightSource, Quantity, Paper, Glass, Aluminium, Steel, Plastic, Wood, Other, 0 AS General 
   FROM 
       DSF.DSFPackagingResults 
   WHERE 
       DSFId = @DSFId 
       AND RuleId = @RuleId;
   SELECT @RuleIndex = @RuleIndex + 1;
   END;
   ```
2. Call the report directly

   ```
   --Method #2
   WHILE @RuleIndex <= @MaxRuleIndex
   BEGIN
    DECLARE @DSFId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
   SELECT @DSFId = [GUID] FROM NewGUID; --this has to be deterministic, it isn't but the compiler thinks it is :D
   DECLARE @RuleId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
   SELECT @RuleId = DSFRuleId FROM @DSFRules WHERE DSFRuleIndex = @RuleIndex;
   DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

   --Run the report
   EXECUTE ExecuteDSFRule @ServiceId, @MemberId, @LocationId, @DSFYear, NULL, NULL, NULL, @RuleId, @DSFId, 2;

   --Copy the data out of the results table into our local copy
   INSERT INTO 
       @DSFResults 
   SELECT 
       TableId, TableCode, TableName, RowId, RowName, LocationCode, LocationName, ProductCode, ProductName, PackagingGroupCode, PackagingGroupName, LevelName, WeightSource, Quantity, Paper, Glass, Aluminium, Steel, Plastic, Wood, Other, 0 AS General 
   FROM 
       DSF.DSFPackagingResults 
   WHERE 
       DSFId = @DSFId 
       AND RuleId = @RuleId;
   SELECT @RuleIndex = @RuleIndex + 1;
   END;
   ```

I can think of the following workarounds (none of which are particularly satisfactory):

- rewrite some of this in CLR (but this is just a whole lot of hassle to break the rules);
- use a stored procedure to produce my report (but this means I lose control of the execution unless I develop a new system for this SINGLE report, different to the dozens of existing reports that all work fine);
- split execution from reporting, so I have one process to execute the report and another that just picks up the output (but no way to tell when the report has completed without more work);
- wait until Microsoft see sense and allow execution of stored procedures from UDFs.

Any other ideas out there?

---

Edit 3-May-2013, here is a (very) simple example of how this hangs together:

```
--Data to be reported
CREATE TABLE DataTable (
    MemberId INT,
    ProductId INT,
    ProductSize VARCHAR(50),
    Imported INT,
    [Weight] NUMERIC(19,2));
INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES (1, 1, 'Large', 0, 5.4);
INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES (1, 2, 'Large', 1, 6.2);
INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES (1, 3, 'Medium', 0, 2.3);
INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES (1, 4, 'Small', 1, 1.9);
INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES (1, 5, 'Small', 0, 0.7);
INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES (1, 6, 'Small', 1, 1.2);

--Report Headers
CREATE TABLE ReportsTable (
    ReportHandle INT,
    ReportName VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO ReportsTable VALUES (1, 'Large Products');
INSERT INTO ReportsTable VALUES (2, 'Imported Small Products');

--Report Detail
CREATE TABLE ReportsDetail (
    ReportHandle INT,
    ReportDetailHandle INT,
    DatabaseColumn VARCHAR(50),
    DataType VARCHAR(50),
    Operator VARCHAR(3),
    FilterValue VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO ReportsDetail VALUES (1, 1, 'ProductSize', 'VARCHAR', '=', 'Large');
INSERT INTO ReportsDetail VALUES (2, 1, 'Imported', 'INT', '=', '1');
INSERT INTO ReportsDetail VALUES (2, 1, 'ProductSize', 'VARCHAR', '=', 'Small');
GO
CREATE FUNCTION GenerateReportSQL (
    @ReportHandle INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT SUM([Weight]) FROM DataTable WHERE 1=1 ';
    DECLARE @Filters TABLE (
        FilterIndex INT,
        DatabaseColumn VARCHAR(50),
        DataType VARCHAR(50),
        Operator VARCHAR(3),
        FilterValue VARCHAR(50));
    INSERT INTO @Filters SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DatabaseColumn), DatabaseColumn, DataType, Operator, FilterValue FROM ReportsDetail WHERE ReportHandle = @ReportHandle;
    DECLARE @FilterIndex INT = NULL;
    SELECT TOP 1 @FilterIndex = FilterIndex FROM @Filters;
    WHILE @FilterIndex IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @SQL = @SQL + ' AND ' + DatabaseColumn + ' ' + Operator + ' ' + CASE WHEN DataType = 'VARCHAR' THEN '''' ELSE '' END + FilterValue + CASE WHEN DataType = 'VARCHAR' THEN '''' ELSE '' END FROM @Filters WHERE FilterIndex = @FilterIndex;
        DELETE FROM @Filters WHERE FilterIndex = @FilterIndex;
        SELECT @FilterIndex = NULL;
        SELECT TOP 1 @FilterIndex = FilterIndex FROM @Filters;
    END;
    RETURN @SQL;
END;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ExecuteReport (
    @ReportHandle INT)
AS
BEGIN
    --Get the SQL
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @SQL = dbo.GenerateReportSQL(@ReportHandle);
    EXECUTE (@SQL);
END;
GO
--Test
EXECUTE ExecuteReport 1;
EXECUTE ExecuteReport 2;
SELECT dbo.GenerateReportSQL(1);
SELECT dbo.GenerateReportSQL(2);
GO
--What I really want
CREATE FUNCTION RunReport (
    @ReportHandle INT)
RETURNS @Results TABLE ([Weight] NUMERIC(19,2))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Results EXECUTE ExecuteReport @ReportHandle;
    RETURN;
END;
--Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function
```

Comment: Can you reduce this question to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: "I won't know who ran the report and when." If this is all you want to achieve, then I am sure there are plenty of solutions out there for capturing these kind of info.

Answer (score 2):

If I was in your situation, I wouldn't try to hack anything. I would setup the objects like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReportCollection] (
    [ReportCollectionID] int,
    [ReportID] int
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReportResult] (
    [ReportID] int,
    [LocationCode] int,
    [LocationName] nvarchar(max)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ExecuteReport] (
    @ReportID int
)
AS
    INSERT [dbo].[ReportResult]
    SELECT @ReportID, 1, N'StackOverflow'
END

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_RetrieveReportCollectionResults] (
    @ReportCollectionID int
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE ([ReportID], [LocationCode], [LocationName])
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[ReportResult] rr
    JOIN [dbo].[ReportCollection] rc
        ON rr.ReportID = rc.ReportID
    WHERE rc.ReportCollectionID = @ReportCollectionID
END
```

And use them like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[ReportCollection] VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[ReportCollection] VALUES (1, 2)

EXEC [dbo].[usp_ExecuteReport] @ReportID = 1
EXEC [dbo].[usp_ExecuteReport] @ReportID = 2

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_RetrieveReportCollectionResults](1)
```

Each time you run your reports, start a new collection. Your application should kick off all of the reports and consolidate the results afterward.

--

If you *really* wanted to call a stored procedure from a udf (please don't), do a search on xp_cmdshell.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this working as a function then the least hacky way would be CLR integration.

You don't have to redo everything - just write a CLR wrapper function that calls the stored procedure & returns the stored procs result set as it's own.1

This way all your current SQL development is untouched.